# JCheckbox display a displayName but save a different value behind the scenes

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a `JCheckbox` to define the name of a person:

```
JCheckBox j = new JCheckBox("displayName");
```

But I need that whenever this checkbox is selected `"ActualName"` is user for processing in the code, but only `"displayName"` be displayed.

Is it possible to display a different value and save a different value at the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Examine tutorial for [`JCheckBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox).

You need to use [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Take any local variable i.e int, String or anything you want as following.
here I will take `int a` as value.

```
    JCheckBox j = new JCheckBox();
    j.setText("Display Name");
```

After Submitting your form in action listner write following code

```
    int a;
    boolean temp=j.isSelected();
    if(temp)
    {
        a=111;
        //if JCheckBox is selected set value
    }
    else
    {
       a=222;
       //if JCheckBox is NOT selected set value
    }
```

Comment: Actually there is list of checkboxes getting populated dynamically and that list I am displaying as a list of Checkboxes...NOw I want the display value of the checkbox to be "X "(which is coming from the list and the actual value to be "Y" which will also be calculated dynamically

Comment: something like the <input> tag in html..which allows the "name" to be set to something and the "value" to be set to something else.

Comment: Check box return boolean value so it is always true or false. so when you select checkbox its value is "true" and when it is not selected it's value is "false"
if you compare with HTML then "setText" is same as "name" and variable "a" in above example is "value" just you have to check if the checkbox is selected or not while setting value.